# d3.js diamond symbol size functionality

Tags: d3.js, size, symbols

I want to use "diamond" symbol in D3. 
I am not sure how the sizing for symbols works in D3. My requirement is:

```
svg = d3.select("svg"); 
svg.append("g").append("path")
    .attr("d", d3.svg.symbol()
    .size( function(d) { return 15 })
    .type( function(d) { return "diamond" }))
    .attr("transform", "translate(250, 150)")    
    .style("fill", "black");
```

I want the height of the diamond to be set to 15px. Can anyone help me on this ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: How is the code you've posted not working?

Comment: Hi Lars, my requirement is to set the height of the diamond to 15px. The above code generates a diamond with 5px width and 9px height :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I need a exact height / width, ended up using something like this to get the "d" attribute:

```
if (shape == "triangle") {
 return "M " + dim / 2 + " 0 L " + dim + " " + dim + " L 0 " + dim + " " + dim / 2 + " 0";
}

if (shape == "diamond") {
 return "M " + dim / 2 + " 0 L " + dim + " " + dim / 2 + " L " + dim / 2 + " " + dim + " L 0 " + dim / 2 + " L " + dim / 2 + " 0";
}
```

where "dim" is the height value.

Answer (score 3):

Following on from the answer by Adam Pearce, I am using the following code, which appears to deliver consistent and accurate results across all of the available `d3.svg.symbol` shapes (e.g. diamond, cross, square etc.):

```
d3.svg.symbol().size(function(d) {
        return (itemHeight * itemHeight) / 2;
     }))
```

Where `itemHeight` refers to a fixed height for the shape.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
.size( function(d) { return 15*15 })
```

From the [documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Shapes#wiki-symbol_size):

> sets the size-accessor to the specified function or constant in *square*
>   pixels

Comment: Thank you Adam !! Yes, but it doesn't seem accurate. The dimension of the diamond is - height: 27.91814613342285, width: 16.118549346923828, y: 136.04092407226562, x: 241.9407196044922